# How to show smallest of numeric value with same id in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query like this

```
SELECT 
  parentOrder.uid,
  patient_name,
  created_date,
  created_time,
  order_test_discount_tbl.standard_rate AS test_rate,
  (SELECT 
    parentOrder.grand_total - SUM(amount_paid) 
  FROM
    order_payment_tbl 
  WHERE order_payment_tbl.date <= parentPayment.date 
    AND order_payment_tbl.order_id = parentOrder.id) AS order_due,
  test_pkg_tbl.name AS `name` 
FROM
  order_tbl AS parentOrder 
  RIGHT JOIN order_payment_tbl AS parentPayment 
    ON parentOrder.id = parentPayment.order_id 
  LEFT JOIN order_test_discount_tbl 
    ON parentOrder.id = order_test_discount_tbl.order_id 
  LEFT JOIN test_pkg_tbl 
    ON order_test_discount_tbl.test_pkg_uid = test_pkg_tbl.uid 
  LEFT JOIN referral_tbl 
    ON parentOrder.referral_id = referral_tbl.id 
  LEFT JOIN blanket_order_tbl 
    ON parentOrder.blanket_order_id = blanket_order_tbl.id 
WHERE parentPayment.date >= '2014-02-07' 
  AND parentPayment.date <= '2014-02-08' 
  AND test_pkg_tbl.name = 'kkk' 
  AND parentOrder.status != 'Cancelled' 
  AND order_test_discount_tbl.test_pkg_uid IS NOT NULL 
  AND parentOrder.origin = 'Premises' 
GROUP BY parentOrder.id,
  DATE,
  test_pkg_tbl.name,
  order_test_discount_tbl.standard_rate 
ORDER BY parentOrder.id
```

This is the table data:

```
uid  patient_name  created_date  created_time  test_rate  order_due  name
JV1  abc           7/2/2014      8:26 AM            1100          0  kkk
JV2  def           7/2/2014      8:26 AM            1100       1000  kkk
JV2  def           7/2/2014      8:26 AM            1100          0  kkk
JV3  ghi           8/2/2014      8:26 AM            1100          0  kkk
JV4  jkl           8/2/2014      8:26 AM            1100          0  kkk
```

Above query returns the table like this.Second and third row has same uid but order_due is different.I need only to show row with minimum order_due from second and third row.What I can do?
Anser should be like this

```
uid  patient_name  created_date  created_time  test_rate  order_due  name
JV1  abc           7/2/2014      8:26 AM            1100          0  kkk
JV2  def           7/2/2014      8:26 AM            1100          0  kkk
JV3  ghi           8/2/2014      8:26 AM            1100          0  kkk
JV4  jkl           8/2/2014      8:26 AM            1100          0  kkk
```

Comment: Could you make the query simpler for our sakes?

Comment: You posted this question just *5* minutes ago, and you're annoyed that no-one has help you yet? There are thousands of people asking questions on here and your question is no more (and indeed, no less) important than anyone else's - they all want help

Comment: Did you try using `min()` in the subquery

Comment: @G one  It doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the query you wrote within the following outer query:

```
SELECT uid, patient_name, created_date, created_time, test_rate, MIN(order_due), name
FROM
( ***your query *** ) q
GROUP BY  uid, patient_name, created_date, created_time, test_rate, name
```